# The basis of extension field contains $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $E$ be a extension of field $F$. It is known that $E$ may be considered as vector space over $F$. Is it always possible to find a basis in $E$ that contains $1$? Maybe it is possible when $E$ is finite extension?

Comment: $E$ is a $F$ commutative  algebra with unity, so there is a $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any vector space $V$, if $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set, then there exists elements $x_{n+1}, \dots, x_m$ (with possibly $m = n$) such that $\{x_1, \dots, x_m\}$ forms a basis.

Since $\{1\}$ is a linearly independent set, the statement follows.